# How to add arbitrary lines of text before write.csv() output in R?

Tags: r, shiny

## minimal reproducible example

I have this code:

```
df <- data.frame(foo = 1:5, bar = 5:1)

bla <- "some text"

write.csv(df, "foobar.csv")
```

I would like the final foobar.csv to look like this:

```
some text

"","foo","bar"
"1",1,5
"2",2,4
"3",3,3
"4",4,2
"5",5,1
```

---

---

## wider context

This is part of a Shiny app where I have this bit in the server function:

```
  output$dlcsv <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0(format(Sys.time(), "%Y%M%e%H%M%S"), ".csv")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datareactive(), file)
    }
  )
```

`output$dlcsv` is a download button, and `datareactive()` is a data frame that I export to a csv named after today's date and time. I would like to add some lines to the text file before the data itself. So, the solution to the above question needs to work in this context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use `cat()` for `bla`, then switch to `write.table()` from `write.csv()` in order to be able to set `append = TRUE`:

```
df <- data.frame(foo = 1:5, bar = 5:1)

bla <- "some text"

cat(bla, "\n\n", file = "foobar.csv")

write.table(df, "foobar.csv", sep = ",", append = TRUE)
```

Resulting `foobar.csv`:

```
some text 

"foo","bar"
"1",1,5
"2",2,4
"3",3,3
"4",4,2
"5",5,1
```

Comment: Yes, this works. In Shiny I used `cat(bla, "\n\n", file = file)` and worked great.